# Find element in a matrix in excel

Tags: excel

I want to search through a matrix (in excel) to find a certain element. I have found some things online that appear to solve this problem but either they require me to know somehow what row or column to look in or I have misunderstood something. I am talking about a case where I know neither the column nor the row and the only way to figure those out is to search the entire matrix. Can anyone help?

(Note: While I have some programming experience in python, I am very new to excel so please keep it simple.)

EDIT: I forgot to say, what I want as output is just the column that value is in. Example: I have the matrix shown below (the headers A,B,C are not part of the area I want to search)

[image]

I want to have a function that takes some number, like 5, and outputs the header of the column that number is in, in this case C.

Comment: can you upload your image show fake data, and result you need?

Comment: And return what?

Comment: Thanks for the questions, edited the post

Comment: Are the numbers unique?

Comment: Yes, all numbers I want to search appear exactly once in the matrix